# Any High Availability CF 8/9 Ent VPS / VDS hosting out there?

Tags: web-hosting, vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Will apreciate it if you could list some that you may know of. Those that I could find are standard. I fould one that is enterprise, but no high availability.

Comment: What is the problem with the question?

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for programming questions and answers.

Comment: Ok. Will ask it elsewhere. How come many questions in the the VPS & web-hosting are not voted down?

Comment: With over a million questions on Stack Overflow, some slip through the cracks.

Answer (score 1):

Nich, I can recommend Edge Web Hosting (www.edgewebhosting.net) as a CF hosting company that could meet your needs. I am (and many others I know are) very satisfied with their support and service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about them, but I have been using hostek.com for about a year. I have had only limited contacted with them because they do a good job.